# How to work with UDP sockets in iOS, swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, udp

I'm trying connect to local esp8266 UDP server. SwiftSocket haven't documentation. CocoaAsyncSocket doesn't work.
How to connect and send data to udp server? What i should do?

I wrote sample UDP python server and tried connect to them via SwiftSocket and CocoaAsyncSocket. I'm don't get feedback from app. Server don't receive connections.
For example- one of the most attempts:

```
    var connection = NWConnection(host: "255.255.255.255", port: 9093, using: .udp)

    connection.stateUpdateHandler = { (newState) in
        switch (newState) {
        case .ready:
            print("ready")
        case .setup:
            print("setup")
        case .cancelled:
            print("cancelled")
        case .preparing:
            print("Preparing")
        default:
            print("waiting or failed")
            break
        }
    }
    connection.start(queue: .global())
    connection.send(content: "Xyu".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8), completion: NWConnection.SendCompletion.contentProcessed(({ (NWError) in
        print(NWError)
    })))
    connection.receiveMessage { (data, context, isComplete, error) in
        print("Got it")
        print(data)
    }
```

Can't connect to the server

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This solution work for me! Thanks  **@Paulw11** 
**Swift 4, XCode 10.1, iOS 12.0** 
Simple connect to the public UDP server (This is NOT optimal version but works):

```
import UIKit
import Network

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var connection: NWConnection?
    var hostUDP: NWEndpoint.Host = "iperf.volia.net"
    var portUDP: NWEndpoint.Port = 5201

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Hack to wait until everything is set up
        var x = 0
        while(x<1000000000) {
            x+=1
        }
        connectToUDP(hostUDP,portUDP)
    }

    func connectToUDP(_ hostUDP: NWEndpoint.Host, _ portUDP: NWEndpoint.Port) {
        // Transmited message:
        let messageToUDP = "Test message"

        self.connection = NWConnection(host: hostUDP, port: portUDP, using: .udp)

        self.connection?.stateUpdateHandler = { (newState) in
            print("This is stateUpdateHandler:")
            switch (newState) {
                case .ready:
                    print("State: Ready\n")
                    self.sendUDP(messageToUDP)
                    self.receiveUDP()
                case .setup:
                    print("State: Setup\n")
                case .cancelled:
                    print("State: Cancelled\n")
                case .preparing:
                    print("State: Preparing\n")
                default:
                    print("ERROR! State not defined!\n")
            }
        }

        self.connection?.start(queue: .global())
    }

    func sendUDP(_ content: Data) {
        self.connection?.send(content: content, completion: NWConnection.SendCompletion.contentProcessed(({ (NWError) in
            if (NWError == nil) {
                print("Data was sent to UDP")
            } else {
                print("ERROR! Error when data (Type: Data) sending. NWError: \n \(NWError!)")
            }
        })))
    }

    func sendUDP(_ content: String) {
        let contentToSendUDP = content.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        self.connection?.send(content: contentToSendUDP, completion: NWConnection.SendCompletion.contentProcessed(({ (NWError) in
            if (NWError == nil) {
                print("Data was sent to UDP")
            } else {
                print("ERROR! Error when data (Type: Data) sending. NWError: \n \(NWError!)")
            }
        })))
    }

    func receiveUDP() {
        self.connection?.receiveMessage { (data, context, isComplete, error) in
            if (isComplete) {
                print("Receive is complete")
                if (data != nil) {
                    let backToString = String(decoding: data!, as: UTF8.self)
                    print("Received message: \(backToString)")
                } else {
                    print("Data == nil")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to get this to work on swift 5.x iOS 13. Sends data no problem, but I cannot seem to get it to receive anything. I am trying to use a python script to send a simple message.

Comment: You saved my life ! Finally I was able to open a connection and to send a message to the server using Swift 5 and without to upgrade my macOS to Catalina ! Thank you ! P.S.: If you need to connect using TCP is also working this example, just change from UDP to TCP.

Comment: how to make the connection to listen for continuously?

Answer (score 12):

You need to wait until your connection is in the `ready` state before you try and send or receive any data.  You will also need to hold a strong reference to your connection in a property to prevent it from being released as soon as the function exits.

```
var connection: NWConnection?

func someFunc() {

    self.connection = NWConnection(host: "255.255.255.255", port: 9093, using: .udp)

    self.connection?.stateUpdateHandler = { (newState) in
        switch (newState) {
        case .ready:
            print("ready")
            self.send()
            self.receive()
        case .setup:
            print("setup")
        case .cancelled:
            print("cancelled")
        case .preparing:
            print("Preparing")
        default:
            print("waiting or failed")

        }
    }
    self.connection?.start(queue: .global())

}

func send() {
    self.connection?.send(content: "Test message".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8), completion: NWConnection.SendCompletion.contentProcessed(({ (NWError) in
        print(NWError)
    })))
}

func receive() {
    self.connection?.receiveMessage { (data, context, isComplete, error) in
        print("Got it")
        print(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! When i'm run this code on empty project (run someFunction() from viewDidLoad() ) i get this error:

Comment: 2019-02-12 22:28:41.553015+0300 Nanopix Pilot[3891:189405] [] nw_socket_service_writes_block_invoke [C1:1] sendmsg(fd 5, 3 bytes) [13: Permission denied]

Comment: You are trying to send a broadcast packet; I am not sure if this is permitted.  It would be better to send a packet to the specific host you are trying to communicate with

Comment: Thank you so much! I successfully connected to public UDP server. Below i write final code