# Swift: Receiving UDP packets from server on serial port monitor but not in ios app

Tags: ios, networking, udp, udpclient, swift5

[image: serial port monitor that shows outpackets being send it seccessfully detects the prtocol number meaning the sent packet was correct]I send UDP packets to a wifi module and receive them and i monitor them in serial port monitor successfully but unable to receive them in iOS app.

I'm using **Network Framework** both for connecting and receive. The connection part works perfectly but when i set a listener to the port, and try to get rsponse the **`receiveMessage`** doesn't get called although i see outpackets that module sends.

```
class func connect()
{
    connection = NWConnection(host: hostUDP, port: portUDP, using: .udp)
    connection?.stateUpdateHandler =
    {
        (newState) in switch (newState)
        {
        case .ready:
            //The connection is established and ready to send and recieve data.
            print("ready")
            self.sendPaket(self.sendingPacket)
            self.receive()
        case .setup:
            //The connection has been initialized but not started
            print("setup")
        case .cancelled:
            //The connection has been cancelled
            print("cancelled")
        case .preparing:
            //The connection in the process of being established
            print("Preparing")
        default:
            //The connection has disconnected or encountered an error
            print("waiting or failed")
        }
    }
    connection?.start(queue: Protocols.sendQueue)
}

class func sendPaket(_ packet:String)
{
    let packet = dataWithHexString(hex: sendingPacket)
    print("converted version to byte is :\(packet)")
    connection?.send(content: packet, completion: NWConnection.SendCompletion.contentProcessed((
        {
            (NWError) in
            print("error in sending packet : \(String(describing:NWError))")
    })))

}

class func receive()
{
    connection?.receiveMessage(completion:
    {
        (data, context, isComplete, error) in
        print("Got it")
        if data != nil
        {
            print("context:\n")
            print((context?.protocolMetadata)!)
            Protocols.receivedPacket = data?.dataToHexEncodedString()
            print("received packet:\n")
            print(Protocols.receivedPacket!)
            let rec = Test()
            rec.label.text = Protocols.receivedPacket
        }
        print("receive error: \(String(describing: error))")
    })
}
```

Comment: What output do you get from your app?  Are you running on a simulator or real device?  Does your module have the correct IP address destination for your app?

Comment: As i said sending works perfect and i see corresponding logs but i get nothing once out packets from module is starting to flood in and i tested both on simulator and real device. How should i check that if module has the correct IP or not?(although i think it does)

Comment: Do you want to receive packets from the device you are sending to or from any device. If the former then you need to `receive` on the connection in your `connect` `stateUpdateHandler`. If the latter then you need to receive on the connection password to the `newConnectionHandler` of your `Listener`

Comment: I only wanna receive from the device and i have set a listener to the exact port that i've sent the packet through that. isn't is correct?

Comment: No. A listener is for new incoming connections. You want to receive on the connection you established and sent on. Your packets will come from a random, high port. The device will send back to that high port.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54640996/how-to-work-with-udp-sockets-in-ios-swift

Comment: yeah i have seen it and tried but only **`send`** func called but not **`receive`**

Comment: You also need to confirm that your wifi device is correctly swapping the send & receive ports. Ie if it receives a packet in port “portUDP” and from port 12345 it needs to send its replies from “portUDP” and to 12345

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200934/discussion-between-light-and-paulw11).