# Swift: In NWConnection class when does receiveMessage(completion:) gets called

Tags: ios, xcode, udp, swift5

I wanna have UDP connection with a wifi module as a server and an iOS as a client and send/receive data (obviously).First i wanted to use Sockets but then i realized Apple has introduced `Network` Framework; So i used `NWConnection` which is a class from `Network` Framework for my purpose and i was successful at sending the data to the device but unable to receive the response (which i am sure exists as i monitor devices I/O packets via serial port monitor).Here is a test version of  the code where i use `netcat` as server to test the connection:

- ViewController Class

```
import UIKit
import Network

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var network: UDPNetwork!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any)
    {
        self.network = UDPNetwork(host: "192.168.200.4", port:"4210")!
        self.network.connect()
    }
}
```

- UDPNetwork Class

```
import Foundation
import Network

class UDPNetwork {

    var hostUDP: NWEndpoint.Host
    var portUDP: NWEndpoint.Port

    private var connection: NWConnection?

    private var queue = DispatchQueue(label: "NetworkQuue", qos: .utility)

    init?(host: String, port: String) {

        guard !host.isEmpty, let portUDP = NWEndpoint.Port(port) else {
            return nil
        }

        self.hostUDP = NWEndpoint.Host(host)
        self.portUDP = portUDP
    }


    func connect()
    {
        connection = NWConnection(host: hostUDP, port: portUDP, using: .udp)
        connection?.stateUpdateHandler =
            {
                (newState) in switch (newState)
                {
                case .ready:
                    //The connection is established and ready to send and recieve data.
                    print("ready")
                    self.sendPaket("Hello")
                    self.receive()
                case .setup:
                    //The connection has been initialized but not started
                    print("setup")
                case .cancelled:
                    //The connection has been cancelled
                    print("cancelled")
                case .preparing:
                    //The connection in the process of being established
                    print("Preparing")
                default:
                    //The connection has disconnected or encountered an error
                    print("waiting or failed")
                }
        }
        connection?.start(queue: self.queue)
    }

    func sendPaket(_ packet:String)
    {
        let packetData = packet.data(using: .utf8)
        self.connection?.send(content: packetData, completion: NWConnection.SendCompletion.contentProcessed(({ (error) in
            if let err = error {
                print("Sending error \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Sent successfully")
            }
        })))

    }

    func receive()
    {
        self.connection?.receiveMessage(completion:
            {
                (data, context, isComplete, error) in
                print("Got it")
                if let err = error {
                    print("Recieve error: \(err)")
                }

                if let rcvData = data,
                    let str = String(data:rcvData, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print("Received: \(str)")
                }

                self.receive()

        })
    }

}
```

Apple Documentation says:

> `receiveMessage(completion:)`
>   Schedules a single receive completion handler for a complete message
>
> > **completion** :
> >     A receive completion is invoked exactly once for a call to receive.

- My Question is:

  1. How can we ***call to receive*** ?
  2. Assuming the `receiveMessage(completion:)` method **is** the ***Call to receive*** and also after receiving complete message calls the completion itself, What could be the problem if it doesn't get invoked?

Related code and more detail about my use case can be found here:
[Swift: Receiving UDP packets from server on serial port monitor but not in ios app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58401093/swift-receiving-udp-packets-from-server-on-serial-port-monitor-but-not-in-ios-a?noredirect=1#comment103158827_58401093)

With these assumptions :

> - We call to receive on the same connection that we send data to
> - UDP is used method for connection
> - Server is tested for swapping ports correctly, meaning it responds  on the same IP,Port that data is sent to

- My Setup:
  13" MacBookPro Early 2015 with MacOS Catalina 10.15 
  Xcode Version 11.0 (11A420a) 
  Swift 5.1 
  target iOS 12+

And this is the result from Wire Shark:
[image]

Comment: Yes, you call `receiveMessage` on your connection once it is active. Did you test with netcat as I suggested?

Comment: Also,  can you update this question with your current code, as the code in your other question doesn't call `receiveMessage` when the connection state is `.ready`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes i tested with netcat and it doesn't get any thing. I used this command `nc -u -l 4210`. I tested the module too and it swaps ports correctly. Also i updated my code on the other question.I literally check everything i have no idea why is this happening. A wild guess: is there any possibility that some sort of app permissions like allowing incoming network traffic for example or sandboxing related capability causing it?

Comment: Its a bit hard to follow your updated code because it is receiving on `Protocols.connection` and it isn't clear whether that `connection` is the same `connection` you are sending on.  Here is a [working, minimal, example](https://gist.github.com/paulw11/e672a59c68762b82a5421f365a579e2d).  It prints out whatever I send using nectar

Comment: That of course, should be "netcat" but nectar would be pretty sweet (Dad joke)

Comment: Hahaha, the thing you mentioned about `connection` is because i have made it a `static var` and i have to refer to the class name first, which is `protocols`. Any way i made another edit and got rid of it (on the stack not on my own code of course). About that example: I'll check it ASAP and give the feedback

Comment: @Paulw11 I tested your code and it works exactly like mine: sends successfully but doesn't get anything and behaves the same in netcat too. I don't know if mentioning this is helpful or not but i am sending ***HEX*** data not ***ASCII***. Also may be i don't work with netcat correctly: I connect my mac to wifi module by selecting it from the list of available wifis and then i run this command `nc -u -l 4210`  in terminal then try to send data using simulator but doesn't get anything neither in terminal nor xcode log

Comment: I should mention this that during the test i tweaked your code the line corresponding to sending ASCII and changed it to HEX

Comment: I am not sure whether you are testing corrrectly The idea is to have have the iOS app connect to netcat (which is a known working implementation of a UDP service) and that way you know whether the problem is in your wifi module or in your iOS code. It shouldn't matter which network your Mac is on, but you need to app to communicate with the Mac, not the wifi module.  I had no problem running the test code in the simulator - It connects to netcat running in a terminal session on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Start with my code as-is and once you have packets being sent and received then you can look at the data format you want to use.  It is possible that something in your hex conversion code is causing a problem.

Comment: @Paulw11 I tested your code as is and here is the result:
In the simulator it sends successfully but couldn't get the response.In physical device it sends successfully and calls the receive but couldn't get the message ;here is the log:`Preparing
ready
2019-10-27 21:17:32.912918+0330 wifitest[11872:3195339] [] nw_socket_get_input_frames [C1:1] recvmsg(fd 4, 9216 bytes) [61: Connection refused]
Sent successfully
Got it
Recieve error: POSIXErrorCode: Connection refused
waiting or failed
Got it
Recieve error: POSIXErrorCode: Socket is not connected
Got it`

Comment: Is that log from the iOS app or the device? It looks like a problem with your device since you got a connection refused message.

Comment: @Paulw11 It is the log that Xcode provides when i run the iOS app on physical device. How can i solve it?

Comment: Is that log when you test against your device? What happens when you test your app against Netcat? What happens when you use netcat to communicate with your device instead of your app?

Comment: @Paulw11 when i say physical device i mean iphone not wifi module. I didn't use the wifi module but i didn't use netcat either.

Comment: So you ran my code on the simulator and a physical device?  The code isn't designed to work in that way. My code initiates a connection to a listening device, sends a packet and the displays whatever the listening device sends back. You would need a different implementation if you want an iOS app that acts as a listening device.

Comment: @Paulw11 could you explain a little in more detail that how i am i supposed to test your code?, because i tried whtever i knew

Comment: Well, if you run the `nc -l 4210` command in a terminal and then run my code on the simulator (or a real device, but you will need to change the IP from 127.0.0.1 to the ip of your Mac) then you should see "hello" on the terminal. Anything you type on the terminal should be printed by the iOS app. You can then try the same thing with your code; nc is playing the part of your device and confirming that your code is capable of opening a UDP session with a remote, sending data to that remote and getting data back from that remote.

Comment: You could also use something like `nc -u deviceip 4210` to open a connection to your device and confirm that it is correctly sending data back.

Comment: @Paulw11 I did as you instructed but i got the same error on both simulator and device:`Preparing
ready
Sent successfully
2019-11-03 10:49:46.816188+0330 wifitest[2244:550249] [] nw_socket_get_input_frames [C1:1] recvmsg(fd 4, 9216 bytes) [61: Connection refused]
Got it
Recieve error: POSIXErrorCode: Connection refused
waiting or failed
Got it
Recieve error: POSIXErrorCode: Socket is not connected
Got it`

Comment: @Paulw11 I ran the code again on device and changed the IP to my Mac's IP, the error went away but also receive didn't get called

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code you are running as a [mcve], where you are running it (device or simulator) and the command you are running on your Mac.

Comment: @Paulw11 I did that

Comment: I really don't understand what is happening for you.  I created an app with your code.  Ran `nc -u -l 4210` on my Mac and then ran the app on an iPhone. I connected to the IP address of my Mac.  In the terminal on my Mac I saw "Hello".  Whatever I typed into the terminal on my Mac was received by the app and printed when I pressed enter. Xcode console: `Preparing
ready
Sent successfully
Got it
Received: hi there`.  Terminal `nc -u -l 4210
Hellohi there
`

Comment: I am not sure where the *Serial* application you linked to comes into this.

Comment: @Paulw11 No the serial comes into play when we connect to wifi module.

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried two different MacBooks and 3 different iPhones, i don't understand what is happening either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201785/discussion-between-paulw11-and-bavafaali).