# can't get response from UDP request

Tags: swift, iphone, sockets, udp

is it possible to send UDP message to one ip address but listen on different one, I was using this example : [How to work with UDP sockets in iOS, swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54640996/13965491). With this example I was able to sent UDP message without any problems, but while listening can't get anything.

Comment: there might be some sort of firewall or NAT between the phone and whatever it's talking to.  if that's the case, then there are various "hole punching" techniques available to you, but it's probably easiest to just send a packet from your "receiving" socket to wherever you're expecting traffic from

Comment: I managed to fix it. I guess the main problem was if you are using udp socket from Network library it has deactivated broadcast communication, and all incoming packet are not accepted. I fixed it with CocoaAsyncSocket library where you can enable broadcas in your created socket.